# update panel is preventing JQuery from running

Tags: jquery, asp.net, updatepanel

I have problem on with update panel that preventing jquery from running. like when the page loading the jquery for fraction of second but after the page loaded it will remove Jquery effect it. I ran the jquery function on console & it work fine. also I remove the updatepanel from the page and work fine just asking how can i fix the update panel problem ?

Comment: Could you include some code that demonstrates the problem you're seeing?

Comment: does your jquery work before the update panel has been fired (ie on first page load?)

Comment: yes, it is on first page load

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your call from update panel is Asynchronous jquery is not  called(loaded) during asynchronous call see [Update panel issue with jquery](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/601683/Working-with-jQuery-within-the-ASP-NET-UpdatePanel)

Try the following:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            BindEvents();//your jquery method
        });
```

This script tag binds the BindEvents method .It main  use to support the Jquery 
    for Update panel as the call is Asynchronous

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Create the event handler for PageRequestManager.endRequest
    var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
    prm.add_endRequest(BindEvents);// bind BindEvents method to support update panel
</script>
```